Dedekind cuts : establishing the equivalence of 2 definitions of addition on positive cuts
My source is Ayres, *Modern Algebra", $1965$ ed , ch. $7$,  § "additive inverses" , p.$68$.
A cut in $\mathbb Q$ is defined as a non empty proper subset $C$ of the rationals such that (1) if $c$ belongs to $C$, then every rational number $a$ less than $c$ also belongs to $C$ and (2) if $c$ belongs to $C$ there is some rational number $d$ greater than $c$ that also belongs to $C$.
The question deals with positive cuts ( a positive cut being a cut having at leat one strictly positive rational number as element).
The author first defines the sum of two positive cuts as :
$C_1 + C_2 = \mathbb Q^- \cup \{0\} \cup \{ c_1+c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 , c_1\gt 0 , c_2\gt 0 \} $ ,
in words" the sum of two poitive cuts is the set having as elements all the negative rational numbers , together with $0$ and all possible sums of two members of the positive parts of these cuts".
Then he states that the above definition is esquivalent to :
$C_1 + C_2 = \{ c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 \}$.
Since the author does not provide a proof, my question is : how to
justify this equivalence? I assume it does not simply go without saying
The proof amounts to proving that, for all $x$
$x\in \mathbb Q^- \cup \{0\} \cup \{ c_1+c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 , c_1\gt 0 , c_2\gt 0 \} \iff  x\in \{ c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 \}$.
I'm already stuck for the $\implies $ part, see (3) below  :
(1) if $x\in \mathbb Q^-$ , then , $x = q_1 + q_2 , $ for some $q_1$ and $q_2$ such that both  $q_1$ and $q_2 \in \mathbb Q^- $, implying that both $q_1$ and $q_2$ belong to $C_1$ and $C_2$, and that, in particular $q_1 \in C_1,$ and $q_2 \in C_2$ ;
(2) if $x\in \{ c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 \}$ the consequence follows ipso facto ;
(3) but  if $x=0$ , either $ x= 0+0$ and the consequance  follows; or  $x = q_1+q_2 $ with , say $q_1 \lt 0$ and $q_2 \gt 0$ and $ q_2 = - q_1$ ; however, one cannot - apparently - rule out the possibility that $q_1$ is so small that its opposite $q_2$ is too big to belong to $C_2$ , implying that $x$ is not the sum of two elements of , respectively, $C_1$ and $C_2$.

I'd start by showing that $C_1+C_2$ is, in fact, a cut, under both definitions. Then, to handle the third case, try using the fact that if $c\in C$ for some cut $C$ and $a\in\Bbb Q$ with $a<c,$ then $a\in C.$

Bear in mind all negative rationals and $0$ are all in both $C_1$ and $C_2$.   if $x \in \mathbb Q^-$ then $x \in C_1$ and $0 \in C_2$ and so $x=x+0\in { c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 }$.  And if $x = 0$ then $x=0 + 0$ and $0 \in C_1$ and $0 \in C_2$ so $0\in { c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 }$.  I'd say the only two significant things to show are  If $q= c_1 + c_2 > 0$ but we don't know the signs of $c_1,c_2$ that there exist $d_1,d_2>0$ so that $d_1+d_2=q$ .  Do you need help with that.

@fleablood  I understand your proof of case (3) and I draw the conclusion from it that I've mistaken the existential quantifier ( actually involved in the statement) with the universal one ( that is not involved), As to the " two significant things" you point to, I don't really see what you're referring to.  Anyway, sincere thanks !

@fleablood  Maybe the property needed to prove the " two significant things" is the density property? Am I on the right track?

Oops.  I originally meant that we had to prove as a second thing that if $q > 0$ and $q < c_1+c_2$ for some $c_1,c_2$ then $q = d_1+d_2$ for some $d_1 + d_2$ but I decide that was both confusing to write and redundent.  So I omitted it but forgot to edit my comment about "two things".

The only significant thing to prove is that ${ c_1 + c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 }\cap {q\in \mathbb Q|q > 0}$ is equal to ${ c_1+c_2 | c_1\in C_1 , c_2 \in C_2 , c_1\gt 0 , c_2\gt 0 }$.  We can do that:  If $0 < w = c_1 + c_2$ but $c_1 \le 0$ then $w \le c_2$ so $w\in C_2$.  So $w = 0 + w$.  As $0\in C_1$ there is teensy $r > 0$ that is in $C_1$ and $w = r + (w-r)$.  And $w-r < w$ so $w-r \in C_2$.  So $r\in C_1, w-r \in C_2$ and we are basically done.

The easiest way to think about cuts is that a cut is all the rationals up to but not including a particular point.  So if a cut has a positive rational in it, then it must have all negative rationals, it must have $0$ and it must have an infinite number of arbitrarily small positive rationals.
